# How to change case for alternative letters of a string

Tags: python, string, for-loop

I would like to convert every other letter of a string into uppercase. For example provided the input is `'ahdjeryu'`, the result should be `'AhDjErYu'`.

**I was trying this:**

```
def mycode(letters):
    myword = letters.split()
    for i in letters:
        if i%2 == 0:
            return i.upper()
        else:
            return i.lower()
print(mycode('ahdjeryu'))
```

The error thrown as: 
    `if i%2==0:`

> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: please use like this `for i in range(len(letters))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several issues with your code:

1. You only need to use `str.split` to remove whitespace. Here, not necessary.
2. To extract the index of a letter as well as the letter, use `enumerate`.
3. `return` will return just one letter. You can instead `yield` letters and then use `str.join` on the generator.

Here's a working example:

```
def mycode(letters):
    for idx, i in enumerate(letters):
        if idx % 2 == 0:
            yield i.upper()
        else:
            yield i.lower()

print(''.join(mycode('ahdjeryu')))

AhDjErYu
```

The above logic can be equivalently implemented via a generator comprehension:

```
res = ''.join(i.upper() if idx % 2 == 0 else i.lower() for idx, i in enumerate(letters))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `i` is a string of one character, not an index. So you can't do `i%2`. Use `enumerate` to get both the index and the value.

```
alternating = ''.join(letter.upper() if index%2==0 else letter.lower() for index, letter in enumerate(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it error, cause `i` now is letter not a number, so it can't mod for 2.

Im not sure syntax about looping by `for` in Python but may you can try:

```
    cnt = 0 
    for i in letters:
        if cnt%2 == 0:
            return i.upper()
        else:
            return i.lower()
        cnt++
```

Hope it can help you!

Fix me if I have any wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@Abhi, this is inline with your original logic. You need `r` to get the index of the letters in the string.

```
def mycode(letters):
    for ch in letters:
        r=letters.index(ch)
        if r%2 == 0:
                letters=letters.replace(ch,letters[r].upper())
        else:
                letters=letters.replace(ch,letters[r].lower())      
    return letters
print(mycode('ahdjeryu'))
```